IEEE Xplore paper claim to acheive exponentiation inversion suitable for pairing in polynomial time. Is it trustworthy?
I just found https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6530387. Given the multiplicative group factorization in the underlying finite field of a target bn curve, they claim to acheive exponentiation inversion suitable for pairing inversion in seconds on a 32 bits cpu.
On 1 side, the paper is supposed to be peer reviewed by the iee Xplore journal and they give examples on 100 bits. On the other side, in addition to the claim, their algorithm 2 and 3 are very implicit, and as an untrained student, I fail to understand how to implement them, though I fail to understand things like performing a Weil descent. Or rephrased, when you look at the details for actually implementing the algorithm, lack of details seems to tell nothing is done.
Is the paper untrustworthy, or would it be possible to get code that can be run ?

I can share a copy of the paper privately if needed.

The professor is still at OKAYAMA: https://isec.ec.okayama-u.ac.jp/home/nogami/#research You should email him and ask.  If you are a student, you'll likely be given what you want due the cultural SENSEI->GAKUSEI relationship.  (also, the example on the last page could be used as test vectors for the method described in the paper)

@bdegnan of course, I did it 2 weeks ago. But I lost my university email address in an event that lead the univerisity’s president being scapegoated and fired and such researchers typically don’t reply to non scholar addresses.

The paper should be assessed on it's own merit. But glancing at the table of content of the publication, it's clear the selection of topics covered is uh, wide: 130 papers in the ICCCT2012 track alone. I would not bet the house on careful peer review. E.g. based on titles and abstracts, there are 2 papers on image encryption using the logistic map (The Medical Image Watermarking Algorithm Based on DFT and Logistic Map and The Medical Image Watermarking Algorithm Using DWT-DCT and Logistic), a common theme for poor crypto.

TL;DR: the paper has serious flaws. Even when corrected as this answer does, it has no cryptographic relevance.

The power root calculation for the exponentiation inversion problem (paywalled, no DOI) is about finding a solution $M$ of the equation $M^n=A$ in the group $\mathbb F^*_{p^m}$ when the factorization of $n$ is known, applied to $m=12$ of Barreto–Naehrig curves of prime order $r\lesssim p$, and $n=(p^m-1)/r$, which factorization is reduced to that of $(p^4-p^2+1)/r\;$, $p^2+1\;$, $p^2+p+1\;$, $p^2-p+1\;$, $p+1\;$, $p-1\;$. Each prime factor $q$ of $n$ is handled in succession to obtain a solution.
For the factor $q=2$ the authors report they "used an algorithm of Tonelli and Shanks" with a reference that describes this algorithm for square root modulo $p$. There's a known extension to square root modulo $p^m$ (it's already in Alberto Tonelli's article of 1891) and that was instrumental in making me err into believing the authors are working in the multiplicative group modulo $p^m$, often noted $\mathbb Z^*_{p^m}$ in cryptographic context.
Thanks to Matthew Towers for straightening that they don't: $\mathbb F^*_{p^m}$ is the multiplicative group of the finite field $\mathbb F_{p^m}$, with it's single non-invertible element $0$ removed, so that the multiplicative group has order $p^m-1$, when $\mathbb Z^*_{p^m}$ has order $(p-1)p^{m-1}$. Elements of the field can be seen as the polynomials of degree (at most) $m-1$ with coefficients in the field $\mathbb F_p$. Addition is polynomial addition. Multiplication is polynomial multiplication followed by reduction modulo some irreducible polynomial of degree $m$. It's not related to multiplication modulo $p^m$.
The paper incorrectly states

Let $A\in\mathbb F^*_{p^m}$ be an element of order $r$

If that was the case, the single solution would be $M=A^{n^{-1}\bmod r}$. But I guess we must read that the order of $A$ is a divisor of $(p^m-1)/r$.
Odd $q$ appearing a single time in the factorization of the group order $p^m-1$ are correctly handled by the following Algorithm 2 to compute $q^\text{th}$ root of $A$:

Input: $A\in\mathbb F^∗_{p^m},\,q,\,s=p^m-1$
Output: $A^{\frac1q}\in\mathbb F^∗_{p^m}$

$t\gets\frac s q$
$u\gets -t^{-1}\bmod q$
$B\gets A^{\frac{u\;\!t+1}q}$


Justification of correctness (not given), assuming that $A$ is such that $M^q=A$ has a solution: The stated condition on $q$ ensures that step 1 yields an integer $t$ coprime with $q$. Thus $u$ of step 2 is well-defined, and yields $u$ with $u\;\!t+1=j\;\!q$ for some integer $j$. Thus $B$ of step 3 is $A^j$ and well-defined. By construction of $B$, it holds $B^{\;\!q}=A^{{\frac{u\;\!t+1}q}\;\!q}=A^{u\;\!t+1}=(A^t)^u A=((M^q)^t)^u A=(M^u)^{q\;\!t} A=(M^u)^s A=1A=A$.
Note: $B$ is only one of $q$ solutions $M$. The other ones are the product of $B$ and powers $1$ to $q-1$ of an element of order $q$.
The few odd $q$ appearing more than one time in the factorization of the group order $p^m-1$ are supposedly handled by Algorithm 3, but it's incorrect in it's precondition, and it's step 2. A correct version is just Algorithm 2 replacing $q$ by $q^\ell$, and the precondition that $q$ divides $p^m-1$ exactly $\ell$ times.
In fact it turns out we can use Algorithm 2 for $q$ any positive integer dividing $s$ with $\gcd(s/q,q)=1$. That works for $q=2^\ell$ (where it's unclear what the papers does). That also works directly for $q=n=(p^m-1)/r$ of the application to BN curves, simplifying the procedure. The above justification of correctness and note on finding other solutions are adapted similarly.
The paper correctly explains there are $n$ solutions and characterizes them starting from the one $M_0$ thus obtained, but does not explain how to obtain a random one among the $n$, as the OP asks. One technique is to take a random $R\in\mathbb F^*_{p^m}$ and compute $M=R^r\;\!M_0$.
Illustration of these methods in SageMath: for the 100-bit parameters in the annex, find a random $A$ that's an $n^\text{th}$ power, find and verify the paper's $M_0$, find and verify a random solution $M$. It runs in a small fraction of a second.
p = 746538240128273668337339384581
r = 746538240128272804312859211181
s = p**12-1
n = s//r
G = GF(p**12,name="x")

while True:
    A = G.random_element()**n
    if A!=0: break

M0 = A**((pow(-r,-1,n)*r+1)//n) # article's code fixed, as one line
print(M0**n == A)
print(M0)

while True:
    R = G.random_element()
    if R!=0: break
M = R**r * M0
print(M**n == A)
print(M)

The paper's abstract, introduction and conclusion state relevance of the problem to breaking pairings on BN curves. That's based on their reference [7] (Naoki Kanayama, Eiji Okamoto: Approach to pairing inversions without solving Miller inversion, in IEEE ToIT 2011). Indeed [7] affirms that some class of pairing can be inverted if the Exponentiation Inversion is tractable, that they define as#:

For an unknown element $M\in\mathbb F^∗_{p^m}$, assume that an integer $n$ and the value of $A:=M^n\in\mathbb F^∗_{p^m}$ are known. Then, the EI, or $(n,A)$-EI, is the problem of finding $M$ from the instance $(n,A)$.

This answer explains why that EI problem is not $n^\text{th}$ root extraction in a finite field, something the paper misses. In a nutshell: EI asks to find the one $M$ that was used to compute $A$, not one of possibly many $M$ that would have given the same result. That not a computational problem, but one of divination, or attacking an implementation using e.g. side channel or fault attack.

Note: I take no position on if finding a random solution to $M^n=A$ in the group $\mathbb F^*_{p^{12}}$ for $n=(p-1)^{12}/r$ and $r$ the prime order of a BN curve in the field $\mathbb F_p$ is relevant to inversion of a pairing based on that BN curve. I state it costs $\mathcal O((\log_n)^3)$ with standard algorithms, while finding the one random $M$ which raised to the power $n$ gave $A$ has vanishing probability to succeed.

# Notation adjusted for consistency with the rest of this answer.

Silly remark: as an aside, I observe that it's only considered BN curves on prime field $\mathbb F_p$ with $p=36\chi^4-36\chi^3+24\chi^2-6\chi+1$ and prime order of the full elliptic curve group $r=36\chi^4-36\chi^3+18\chi^2-6\chi+1\;$, but BN curves currently proposed for constructing pairings like BLS12-381 use different parameters, with $p=\frac{(\chi-1)^2(\chi^4-\chi^2+1)}3+\chi$ and a subgroup of much smaller prime order $r=\chi^4-\chi^2+1$.

Thanks for reading it through. I'd call this "taking $q$th roots" rather than "exponentiation inversion". The whole paper does sound underwhelming. On the terminology of pairing-friendly curves, the $p=36\chi^4-36\chi^3+24\chi^2-6\chi+1$ family are the one's that I think of as BN curves as these are the one's described in the original Barreto-Naehrig paper. Other constructions are related and people's usage may vary.

@fgrieu my problem is this: once I solve the qth root for each prime factor, how do I determine the qth root for the whole field given the results ? In the end I care only about bn curves.

"The algorithms in the paper are about solving for $X$ the equation $X^q=A$ in the field $\mathbb F_{p^m}$, given $A$ of known prime order $r$"; huh, isn't this an easy problem - $X = A^{q^{-1} \bmod r}$  Am I missing something?

@fgrieu the timings are constant, so it’s an improvement. Otherwise, that’s the point, when I try to implement the underlying idea in a programming language, things start to look problematic. I’m meaning the paper seems to not describe anything with enough details.

@poncho: I was mislead by the paper's explicit statement that the order of $A$ is a known prime $r$. However that does not hold in the application made to BN curves, because $r$ does not divides $\phi(p^m)$.

@fgrieu though there’s a typo in your answer. Pairing inversion is about looking for the original pairing that lead to finite field’s element. My understanding is it’s possible to generate a pairing that lead to the given field element from a qth root, isn’t it ? Also' in my case I manged to get the odd factors you are talking about on altbn128

The order of $\mathbb{F}{p^m}^$ really is $p^m-1$, like the paper says, because every nonzero element of a field is invertible.  It's $(\mathbb{Z}/p^m\mathbb{Z})^$ which has order $\phi(p^m)=p^{m-1}(p-1)$, and $\mathbb{Z}/p^m\mathbb{Z} \neq \mathbb{F}{p^m}$ unless $m=1$.

@MatthewTowers: the paper explicitly defines $\mathbb{F}^{p^m}$ as "the multiplicative group in $\mathbb{F}{p^m}$", and you are entirely right that I confused that with $(\mathbb{Z}/p^m\mathbb{Z})^$, silly me. I should not do math with the flu.

Without being able to see the paper, it sounds like a plausible observation, though not necessarily a cryptographically relevant one. I'm going to use the words "discrete logarithm" in place of "exponentiation inversion".
Elliptic curve pairings map certain pairs of points on elliptic curves to a subgroup of the multiplicative group of some finite field $\mathbb F^\times_{p^k}$, of order, say, $m$:
$$e(P,Q):E(\mathbb F_{p^k})\times E(F_{p^k})\to F^\times_{p^k}.$$
Now, if $m$ factors into small prime numbers and we know this factorisation, we can solve discrete logarithms in the subgroup using the Pohlig-Hellman attack. The ability to solve discrete logarithms in this way should also allow us to invert pairings as follows. Let $g$ be a generator for the subgroup of our multiplicative subgroup and choose various points $P$ and $Q$ then lets solve some discrete logarithms until we have a pair such that $e(P,Q)=g^a$ where $a$ is coprime with $m$. Now if we are presented with an element $h$ of our subgroup and asked to find a pair of points whose pairing is $h$, we can find the discrete logarithm of $h$, say, $h=g^b$ and then compute $c\equiv b/a\pmod m$. Finally, let $R$ be the point $cQ$. We now claim that $e(P,R)=h$. This is because
$$e(P,R)=e(P,cQ)=e(P,Q)^c=(g^a)^c=g^b=h.$$
The observation is unlikely to be cryptographically relevant as pairing-friendly cryptography should use pairings where the Pohlig-Hellman attack is infeasible.

Except than when a subgroup is 254bits long you can t apply Pohlig Hellman. The paper in the exemple claim to solve exponentiation inversion even with a 600 bits subgroup.

Do you have en email address so I can send a watermarked copy to you ?

@user2284570 I've initiated a chat room

A private chatroom where ?

Upon examination, the paper is about a method for solving $A=X^n$ in $\mathbb F^*_{p^m}$ under some assumptions including that $n=(p^m-1)/r$ has known factorization. That was hard to guess from the abstract, which does claim relevance to the security of pairings on BN curves.
